# Liferay: Theme does not load portlet's CSS

Tags: css, themes, liferay, portlet

I am putting a portlet inside theme using `$theme.runtime("portletId")` but it does not load the CSS in the main.css of the portlet.

What i mean is that the CSS i've written in main.css inside the portlet does not show in the page when i embed the portlet in the theme even though the CSS file is specified in liferay-portlet.xml

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I am not able to understand your problem?

Comment: i edited it the question.

Comment: did you add this property "<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>" to your liferay-portlet.xml and "portlet.add.default.resource.check.whitelist=portlet_id" to your portal-ext.properties file ?

Comment: `<add-default-resource>true</add-default-resource>` this is required when you want to add your portlet dynamically to a page. This should solve your problem. Thanks @LuckyBoy, why not convert this to an answer?

Comment: i have add the default resource property. and created the portal-ext file in webapps/root/web-inf/classes  but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The portlet which you have embedded in your theme is OOB portlet or custom portlet?

If you have embedded custom portlet then you should write all your css inside custom.css file, which you should create in order to apply css to your portlet.

And if you are using OOB portlet then you should add classes to the required .jsp files and add its respective css to the theme.

Do look this - http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/21118773

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your css code to the custom.css file inside /docroot/_diffs/css, that has higher priority over main.css